# Python and Outlook - Marking message thread as 'read'

Tags: python, outlook, jira, office-automation, com-automation

My company uses JIRA to track issues, and is set up to send an e-mail to all watchers and tagged users whenever an update is done on the issue. We also have some automation in place that will adjust fields on the issue (like sprint number) whenever it gets closed (this'll also send an e-mail). I also have a filter within Outlook that'll put any e-mail from JIRA into a separate subfolder 'JIRA'.

I often receive e-mails on issues that have been closed. I'm trying to write a small Python script that'll mark all these e-mails as read if the JIRA issue has been closed already. The basic idea is I can run this script once a week or so to clean up my mailbox.

I'm using the pywin32 and jira packages to do this, but I can't figure out how to change a message status. The fact that documentation is scarce doesn't help...

What I have:

```
import re
import textwrap

from jira import JIRA
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client

jira = JIRA("<JIRA URL>", None, ("<USER>", "<JIRA API key>"))
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(initial_indent="", width=100, subsequent_indent=" " * 4)
days_back = 10
start_time = pd.to_datetime("now").floor("D") - pd.to_timedelta(days_back, unit="D")
for message in outlook.getDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Item("JIRA").Items.Restrict(f"[ReceivedTime] >= '{start_time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p')}'"):
    if message.Unread:
        jira_issue = re.search("\[JIRA\] \([A-Z0-9-]+\)", str(message)).group().split()[1][1:-1]
        print(message, jira_issue)
        print(message.body)
        issue = jira.issue(jira_issue)
        status = issue.fields.status
        if status in ("Done", "Checked"):
            message.Unread = False
```

as noted in [this SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152457/python-command-to-mark-mails-as-read-in-outlook-mapi). This doesn't seem to mark any e-mail as read.

Is this something I can even do in Python? If so, how? If not, what could be an alternative approach?

Comment: `message.Unread = False` is just a local change, where are you sending any updates back to the server?

Comment: So what happens? Does the line `message.Unread = False` get executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.categories) property to assign a red category to items in Outlook. `Categories` is a delimited string of category names that have been assigned to an Outlook item. This property uses the character specified in the value name, sList, under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International` in the Windows registry, as the delimiter for multiple categories. See [Setting an Outlook mailitem's category programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162449/setting-an-outlook-mailitems-category-programmatically) for more information.

Comment: In your linked SO question, they use mailItem.Save(); to pass through any changes made, and that seems to do the trick! No idea why that didn't occur to me, since Save() is shown on dir(message)...